# How can I do this faster and more efficiently?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var url = "myurl.com/hwid.txt";
var client = new WebClient();
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
  string downloadedString;
  while ((downloadedString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    if (downloadedString == finalHWID)
    {
      update();
      allowedIn = true;
    }
  }
  if (allowedIn == false)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("You are not allowed into the program!", name, 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
```

This will check your HWID against a list of allowed ones. However, it takes about 5-10 seconds each time it finishes checking. Is there a way that will make it go faster?

Comment: Have you run even the most basic of tests to see what is taking the most time?  What does `update()` do?

Comment: @EdS. Yes, I have. It's reading from the website that takes time. I should have put that in the question, sorry. Update just allows access by deleting a group that covers the whole program to prevent you from doing anything.

Comment: "It's reading from the website that takes time" --- well, buy a faster broadband then

Comment: @zerkms I've had other people test it for me, they all say it takes 5-10 seconds. Try it for yourself.

Comment: If other people have the problem too, then it is down to the server and I don't think you can do anything about that... On a different note, instead of reading the stream line by line, could you readtoend() and then do a if .contains(finalHWID) on the string you read in? Not sure if it's faster, but the code would be more compact.

Comment: @user643192 I thought that at first, but I've tried two hosts (x10hosting and 2freehosting), paid accounts, and they both took roughly the same amount of time.

Comment: Wow, ok... Last thing I can think of then, have you asked the hosting customer service if they know why this is taking so long or if they have a recommended method for accessing the server?

Comment: Do it on the server, send you HWID up, have it check against this list, maybe

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm confused as to what you mean, can you rephrase it? It sounds like you're suggesting to just delete everything and start over again.

Comment: @chipperyman573 Everything? As in change the 14 lines of code you have for hwid check on the client? Hardly everything is it? Your code is equivalent to doing select * from HardwareTable and then looping through with a DataReader or Dataset and testing your value agaisnt each one in the table. I'm saying do select * from HardwareTable where HWID = 'MyBox'.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `break` once a match was found:

```
var url = "myurl.com/hwid.txt";
var client = new WebClient();

using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string downloadedString;
    while ((downloadedString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (downloadedString == finalHWID)
        {
            update();
            allowedIn = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (allowedIn == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are not allowed into the program!", name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Because you avoid reading (or even streaming it over the network) the rest of hwid.txt - which could be large?

Comment: Oh, good point. But the HWID.txt file only has 4 lines in it.

Comment: @chipperyman573 We didn't know that. Also, what did you expect to improve on, then? :) The web request is the thing that takes the time...